# Comparação entre variáveis PHP e mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Não tenho muita ideia de como fazer uma 'comparação' entre 2 variáveis no exemplo abaixo:**

```
if ($rows['block'] == $idBlock ) {/*....*/} else {/*....*/}
```

Até ai da certo, pois se o id cadastrado for igual o que está no mysql vai funcionar, mas terá vários ids separados por virgulas,ex: `'aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd'` e gostaria de saber se é possível a 'comparação' percorrer todas as linhas da string no mysql e ver se acha algo igual à variável de bloqueio individual (idBlock).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pode resolver esse problema convertendo essa string (`$row['block']` em um array com a função `explode()` por fim basta comparar com `in_array()` se o valor (`$id`) informado existe na lista de itens bloqueados.

```
$blocks = explode(',', 'aa,bb,cc,dd');
$id = 'aa';

if(in_array($id, $blocks)){
    echo $id . ' existe em: $blocks';
}else{
    echo 'item não encontrado';
}
```

Comment: @PedroHenrique seu código final deve ficar `$blocks = explode(',', $rows['block']);`

Answer (score 3):

Primeiramente você precisa separar os valores que estão com vírgula para só após isso você conseguir comparar um por um, veja;

```
$ids = explode(',', $rows['block']);
// a saída sera um array: ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd']
```

com os `ids` separados você pode realizar um loop com `foreach` ou utilizar a função `in_array` nativa do `PHP`.

Usando `foreach`:

```
foreach($ids as $id) {
    if ($id == $idBlock) {
        /*
            trate caso os ids sejam iguais
        */
    }
}
```

Usando `in_array`:

```
if (in_array($idBlock, $ids)){
    /* O ID existe na lista em questão */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Olhe o exemplo se cada id vem de vários registros:

```
if($th = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FORM `sua_tabela`"){
    while($row = $th->fetch_assoc()){
       if ($rows['block'] == $idBlock ) {/
           //Seu código
       } else {
           //Seu código
       }
    }
}
```

Isso vai fazer vc percorrer todos os registros vindos da query, observe que utilizei o modo orientado a objeto, ou seja, minha variável `$mysqli` foi criada assim:

`$mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'senha', 'db');`

Agora se sua pergunta é que cada registro já vem com os ids: "aa,bb,cc..."

O correto a se fazer é como o exemplo dos outros usuários abaixo, utilizando o `explode` com um `foreach` ou o `in_array`